# Repeating functions with XML and movieclips in AS variables

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, loops, variables

I'm new to AS3. Basically I have a grid of 98 UILoaders which each grab an image based on an XML file. Rather than to write out 98 lines of code, is there an easy way to repeat it with different numbers every time?

```
function loadworld() {
    var xmlData:XML = new XML();
    var theURL_ur:URLRequest = new URLRequest("imagepos.xml" + "#lawl=" + (Math.random() * 1000));
    var loader_ul:URLLoader = new URLLoader(theURL_ur);
    loader_ul.addEventListener("complete", fileLoaded);

    function fileLoaded(e:Event):void
    {
        xmlData = XML(loader_ul.data);

        if (t88.source == xmlData.t88) { } else { t88.source = xmlData.t88; };
        if (t89.source == xmlData.t89) { } else { t89.source = xmlData.t89; };
        if (t90.source == xmlData.t90) { } else { t90.source = xmlData.t90; };

        loadworld();
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code the numbers are the same throughout, so I just need to repeat this 98 times going from 1-98.

I'm also having the same problem trying to record a mouse click on all 98 UILoaders:

```
this.t88.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function (){
    pi1(88);
});
```

`t88` means tile 88 or UILoader88 and I need it to activate function `pi1(88)`, then `t89` needs to activate `pi1(89)` etc.

Comment: Why do you distinguish them with different numbers in the xml file? Are they in a particular order or are you just trying to load a list of images and display them in a grid?

Comment: Yeah the xml constantly changes with different images that the grid needs to load so it checks to see if the image is the same first.

"if (t88.soruce == xmlData.t88)" then it changes the UILoader, need to do this 98 times

Comment: @Callum Did you tried to use an array to put your tiles and then you can use for loops to do all operations ?

Comment: I'm not sure on exactly how to use arrays and change the numbers on every loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When manipulating many instances of an object, it's better to use an `Array` ( or `Vector`) to simplify the treatment.

For your case, you can create your `UILoader`s and add them to an array, then for all operations, you can use some for loops like this :

```
// the array where we will save our tiles
var tiles:Array = [];

// creation of tiles
for(var i:int = 0; i < 99; i++){
    var tile:UILoader = new UILoader();

        // save the index of the tail as its name
        tile.name = String(i+1);    

        tile.addEventListener(
            MouseEvent.CLICK, 
            function(e:MouseEvent):void {
                trace(e.currentTarget.name);    // gives : 1, 2, .. , 98

                // you can call your function : pi1(int(e.currentTarget.name));

            }   
        )

    tiles.push(tile);   
    addChild(tile);
}

function load_xml(){

    var xml:XML;
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.load(new URLRequest('xml.xml'));
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, process_XML);

    function process_XML(e:Event):void {    
        xml = new XML(loader.data);
        var tile:UILoader;
        for(var i:int = 0; i < tiles.length - 1; i++){          
            tile = tiles[i];    
            if (tile.source != xml['t'+(i+1)]) tile.source = xml['t'+(i+1)];
        }
    }

}

load_xml();
```

**Edit :**

If your `UILoader`s are in the stage, you can do like this to add them to an array :

```
var tiles:Array = [];
var index:int;
for(var i:int = 0; i < this.numChildren; i++){
    var obj:Object = this.getChildAt(i);
    if(obj is UILoader){
        index = int(obj.name.replace('t', ''));
        tiles[index - 1] = obj;

        obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {
            trace(e.currentTarget.name.substr(1)); // gives 1, 2, ...
        })

    }
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Is it possible to control the UI loaders I already have? Thanks

Comment: How do I then add this into your previous code and make it repeat?

Comment: @Callum I don't know what you mean by "make it repeat" ? If you are speaking about loading xml, take a look on that part in my code.

Comment: Sorry, got it now. You lot are so helpful, thank very much! @akmozo

Comment: When trying to use tile.name = String(i+1);    

        tile.addEventListener(
            MouseEvent.CLICK, 
            function(e:MouseEvent):void {
                trace(e.currentTarget.name);    // gives : 1, 2, .. , 98

                // you can call your function : pi1(int(e.currentTarget.name));

            }   
        )


It says " Access of undefined property tile."

Comment: You know that you changed the code because I already have the UILoaders on the stage. I still need to add the event listener's to them. How can I do this?

Comment: @Callum I edited my last code to add event listener.